# SocialEngine: NOTICE (5): [8] MemcachePool::get(): Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 6379, udp 0) failed with: Malformed VALUE header (0)

Tags: memcached, socialengine

We have supplied port number: 11211 default port though it is taking 6379. Weird and keep throwing error as:

> NOTICE (5): [8] MemcachePool::get(): Server 127.0.0.1 (tcp 6379, udp
>   0) failed with: Malformed VALUE header (0)

Can anyone help us how to resolve the error?

I have searched and found socialengine has this kind of error but cannot find resolution:
http://blog.socialengine.com/2017/04/17/socialengine-php-4-9-0-and-third-party-products/

Comment: Can you please clarify where exactly did you set this port number?

Comment: Inside admin "performance and caching" setting under "Memcache Port" 11211

Comment: are you in development mode?

Comment: Tried both development and production mode. Currently, on production mode

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your `/application/settings/cache.php` file. It contains your caching settings including port, lifetime, serialization etc.

Comment: I found there are setting array like:
`'Memcached' => 
    array (
      'servers' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'host' => '127.0.0.1',
          'port' => 11211,
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'host' => '127.0.0.1',
          'port' => 6379,
        ),
      ),
      'compression' => true,
    ),`
Why there are two memcache array and also with the other port. It should be one only with 11211 what you say?

Comment: @minc have you already tried to change port there to 11211 (this is the number you specified in your answer as correct port number)?